# How can I change the V2V frequency of data transmission in Omnet++?

Tags: omnet++, veins, sumo

I have already got Omnet++, Sumo and Veins running in the Erlangen scenario and it goes smoothly, now I am trying to figure out how to change the v2v communication Frequency, I would like to see if it arrives until the THz range and start varying the data throughput and the speed of the different cars involved in the simulation.

I have got into the NIC and PHY file, but I have not found where to edit this frequency I am talking about.

And also, where can I find the Results of the transmitted data? I mean, where there was a loss of a packet or not, because I just can see the General.anf where you can find the speed, posy, posx, accelaration and emmissions.

If you have any advise or comment, please let me know.

Thanks.

Best, 
Konrad.

Comment: This will need a lot of work on your part. Veins does not include many models of communication in such high frequency ranges. See a textbook on wireless networking for how to model effects that come into play here. If you are interested specifically in visible light communications, I would recommend having a look at the models of Veins VLC